# Unable to design a Layout in android

Tags: android

I have to design a layout, which i have shown below. Here i have 5 vertical layouts and i have attached a image (vertical rectangular one). Now i have to add the horizontal background image as shown in the given figure[image: I have made all the layouts (named 1,2,3,4,5) as vertical and want to have both the horizontal and vertical background as shown below]. I am not getting this thing how to add it in my background because my layouts are vertical.

I have made all the layouts (named 1,2,3,4,5) as vertical
Or is there any other method to make this layout.

**My code is as follows:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_CategoryItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/black_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="60dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <!--
                         <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_CategoryItem"
                        android:layout_width="60dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



                    -->
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Year1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#DBDBDB"
                        android:text="2012"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Year2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:text="2011"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_CategoryItem_RatingSelected"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Rating" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Rating1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="#DBDBDB"
                        android:text="Rating"
                        android:textColor="#C05E09"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Rating2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:text="Rating"
                        android:textColor="#C05E09"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/linear_CategoryItem_MPGSelected"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="MPG" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_MPG1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="#DBDBDB"
                        android:text="MPG"
                        android:textColor="#0B5AAD"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_MPG2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:text="MPG"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/linear_CategoryItem_PriceSelected"
                    android:layout_width="78dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="PRICE" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Price1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Price2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple. You just have to use Frame Layout in which you have to add an image view with the corresponding background and your whole linear layout. To better clarify i have added the xml code in your specified layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_CategoryItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="102dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/black_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:background="#D8D8D8"/>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <!--
                     <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_CategoryItem"
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



                -->
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="17dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Year1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2012"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Year2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:text="2011"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_CategoryItem_RatingSelected"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Rating" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Rating1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Rating"
                    android:textColor="#C05E09"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Rating2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:text="Rating"
                    android:textColor="#C05E09"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/linear_CategoryItem_MPGSelected"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="MPG" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_MPG1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="MPG"
                    android:textColor="#0B5AAD"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_MPG2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:text="MPG"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/linear_CategoryItem_PriceSelected"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="PRICE" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Price1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_CategoryItem_Price2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just change your xml with this one or add the changes in your existing xml.
Hope it works.

Comment: Great, I found my solution. Thanx Gaurav for this support.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a background image to your TextView with `android:background="@drawable/myressource"` or nest a `LinearLayout` with an horizontal orientation for wrapping your `TextView` and add a background image for this layout.

Comment: Actually Emmanuel, I have two textviews which have same square background So I can't put same background on both.So, I unable to implement you solution.